# Links to the help in off-topic reason in closing and flagging dialogs became raw

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, vote-to-close, close-dialog

> [image]

as you can see (and click it to see some more raw links). This happened to all sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the heads-up - this has now been corrected.

Comment: This shouldn't change any types anywhere - it was a rendering bug.